# How to join two separate networks wirelessly

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I need to join two networks like this:

```
PC A1   PC A2   PC A3                                   PC B1   PC B2   PC B3
  \      |       /                                        \      |       /
  ADSL MODEM/ROUTER A  -------- Wirelessly? -------- ADSL MODEM/ROUTER B
      192.168.2.x                                           192.168.1.x
```

What I want to do is to be able to access the network devices of network A from network B and vice versa. And I also want the devices to access the internet via the router on their respective network, for example PC A1 should access the internet via MODEM A and PC B1 via MODEM B.

So, I want things to stay as they are right now, adding the ability for PC A1 to "see" PC B1 etc. so I can transfer files between them etc.

Please note that I have already seen the [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/461255/how-can-i-join-two-networks) for this question but I want to do that same thing wirelessly.

Comment: This is difficult to answer without knowing your technical skill, if the WiFi on network A and/or B  is currently in use and what kind of routers you have.

Comment: The simplest way to do this is to set up a router so WiFi is an AP client (or get another device to act as one if WiFi is already in use) to create a "physical link" between the devices and then add appropriate routes into the routing tables. You will need to ensure network A and B are in different subnets.

Comment: I am new to networking but I understand two things from your comment. First, that I have to add static routes in both the routers and second that they have to be on different subnet. I will try to do that but What I do not understand is how can I set up router so WiFi is an AP Client.

Also, I would really appreciate if you have any article or video handy which explains how to achieve this end to end.

Comment: @forank the problem is there is insufficient into to answer the generic case as the how is device specific. I was surprised that I could not find any tutorials on this for dd-wrt :(    What make routers do you have and is it an option to purchase an additional device (to act only as an AP client) which could make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

To connect two Routers wirelessly, the thing you are looking for is a **Wireless Bridge**.

The answers in this [site](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-connect-two-WiFi-routers-wirelessly) should suffice, using the top answer as an example.

> You can connect two routers wirelessly provided either of them has wireless bridge mode as an option.
>
> So if router A is normal router and router B has bridge mode, then you can configure router B as a wireless bridge.
>
> Log into router B follow the wizard and choose Bridge mode.
> Once the wizard is completed and settings saved, you can test the bridge by plugging an Ethernet cable between router B and your PC and accessing internet.
>
> If internet is working on PC , the bridge setup is complete.

A sweet [5 minute video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2wN4wJ2uMw) that explains the technology and setup perfectly.

Comment: Isn't this just for extending the wireless range? In this scenario, I am not looking to extend the range, but would rather like to join the two different networks so that I can access the network devices of network A from network B.

Comment: Bridging do allow computers on both sides of the network to communicate. Unless a separate VLAN is configured!